# Can the maven checkstyle plugin be used to make sure that test classes have timeout rules?

Tags: java, maven, junit, checkstyle

The maven documentation doesn't seem to cover this:

Is it possible to enforce rules for all classes (such as that all classes should have a log property defined), or for just specific classes (all classes which have junit `@Test` properties on some elements, also have a timeout `@Rule` defined)? If it is possible, how (please link to relevant documentation)?

Answer (score 0):

Plugin just use Checkstyle library, so you need to take a look at Checkstyle project http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net .

There is no such Check for now, but you can implement it easily, how to write a Check - http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html

If you switch discussion to mail list i will show you similar Checks and how quickly integrate your new Check to your maven build.

Comment: hard to fins smth very similar , but review that https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/java/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/annotation/MissingOverrideCheck.java, https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Andrew0701/sevntu.checkstyle/NonAccessibleTypeCheck/sevntu-checks/src/main/java/com/github/sevntu/checkstyle/checks/coding/NonSharableTypeCheck.java

entry point to Check logic is method "visitToken(DetailAST node)"